# initializing java.util.ArrayList using spring bean

Tags: java, spring

i'm developing a web application using spring 3. i'm using tomcat 6 as the web container.

in my web.xml file i bound the file named applicationContext.xml as the spring definition file.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

from inside the applicationContext.xml file i'm trying to initialize a array list variable using the spring bean definition. i'm following the below configurations.. (im using jidea)

```
<bean id="registationController" class="com.test.RegistrationController">
    <property name="registrationService" ref="registrationService"/>
    <property name="validUrlsList" ref="myList"/>
</bean>

<util:list id="myList" value-type="java.lang.String">
    <value>10.1.200.104</value>
    <value>10.1.200.205</value>
</util:list>
```

i have loaded the

```
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
```

namespace, and in RegistrationController.java class i have generated the getter and setter for the validUrlsList variable, jidea shows that my definitions are correct and i have properyly bound my vaiable to the bean definition. but when i try out the code it doesn't initialize the validUrlList variable? it's giving a null value? any thing i'm doing wrong here? any suggestions to sort this out?

java code is as follows.,,

```
private ArrayList validUrlsList;    
public void setValidUrlsList(ArrayList validUrlsList) {
    this.validUrlsList = validUrlsList;
}

public ArrayList getValidUrlsList() {
    return validUrlsList;
}
```

then i call the method getRemoteIp by just passing the variable as follows.

```
if (getRemoteIP(req, validUrlsList)) {
```

-- Regards,Rangana

Comment: Show us how you're trying out the code. And show us the code of RegistrationController. Oh, and the name of your IDE is IntelliJ IDEA. Not jidea.

Comment: modified the question to add the java code? i haven't used XmlBeanFactory, thought it will be initialized as it loads?

Comment: How do you know that the list Spring constructs is an ArrayList? How could it call your setter if the list it constructs from your XML is a LinkedList, or an unmodifiable list? Code against interfaces. Use `List<String>` and not `ArrayList<String>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`util:list` is creating `java.util.List` instance, it is not said to create `java.util.ArrayList`.

You should change your declaration from

```
private ArrayList validUrlsList;
```

to

```
private List validUrlsList;
```

(and setter and getter as well).

Comment: by changing to java.util.List worked, but i had to make the variable static...  private static List validUrlsList; only then i was able to get the list properly. Thanks for the great support. :)